# copiar DOM con sus funciones

Tags: reactjs

estoy buscando hacer un "revert" de mi aplicacion web, por ahora puedo conseguirlo haciendo un query selector de lo que necesito y guardarlo en un array, y funciona, pero mi aplicación pierde toda funcionalidad, quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de copiar el DOM con todas sus acciones, vi que hay un `react-remount`, pero no se como poder implementarlo, tendrán alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Podrías ampliar un poco más tu pregunta para poder ayudarte?. ¿Copiar el DOM? ¿Donde? Llevo años trabajando con React y no me he encontrado con un caso de uso similar

Comment: estoy tratando de hacer como un ctrl+z de lo que voy haciendo, por ejemplo a un div puedo irlo modificando, poniendo texto color hijos, el revert quiero que sea como ir paso a paso atrás de lo que hice, es decir, quitarle los hijos, el color, el texto, por ahora lo consigo pero pierde toda funcionalidad al volver a pintar mi DOM

Comment: por ahora solo guardo en componentWillUpdate un arreglo con cada cambio que se hace, despues solo voy haciendo pop de ese arreglo para lograr hacer el revert, y solo lo pinto como html, pero queda como html plano y ya no me deja por ejemplo ponerle texto color etc

Comment: Me parece un reto interesante el que propones y la verdad que a priori se me ocurría algo parecido a lo que comentas de ir metiendo los cambios en un array en el orden que se producen para poder ir atrás en el mismo orden. Suponque que necesitas guardar un objeto con las características definidas de los cambios para luego poder identíficar qué tipo de cambio. También sería quizá una buena opción usar localStorage para no perder los cambios.

Comment: de hecho de esa forma trabaja muy bien el unico problema es que pierde sus funciones como el onClick y todas esas cosas :(, encontre el react-remount, pero no logro saber como es que puedo implementarlo

Comment: No sé decirte cómo te podría ayudar esa librería, implementarla no parece dificil, si quieres crea un codesandbox donde puedas hacer pruebas y podemos ayudarte desde ahí, viendo el código también.